# How to set a variable's value (string) to be equal to a key in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following array:

```
var deckArray = [
        "card1": ["rank","suit"],
        "card2": ["rank","suit"],
        "card3": ["rank","suit"],
        "card4": ["rank","suit"],
        "card5": ["rank","suit"],
        "card6": ["rank","suit"],
        "card7": ["rank","suit"],
]
```

I clipped the rest of the array for brevity, but the entire thing contains 52 objects. What I want to do is pick a random number from 1 to 52, and set the `firstCardString` property to be equal to whichever key corresponds to that index in the array.

For example, if the random number it generates is `5`, it would set `firstCardString` to be equal to `card5`.

I've tried to do it like so:

```
let firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
let firstCardString:String = self.deckArray[firstRandomNumber]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Array]' with an index of type 'Int'

This doesn't make sense, because `firstCardString:string` is explicitly of type `string`, not int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your deckArray as a Dictionary. So you need to pass a String (key) not an Int

```
let firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))+1
let firstCardString = deckArray["card\(firstRandomNumber)"]
```

Comment: Ah ok. In your answer, what is "card\" meant to represent?

Comment: That's string interpolation to convert the random Integer to string and compose your dictionary key