# How do I target an array which's name is equal to a variable's value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
// here goes random number generator

// arrays with info

foo1 = ["This is true!", true, false];
foo2 = ["This is false!", false, false];
foo3 = ["This is probably false!", false, false];
foo4 = ["This is probably true!", true, false];
foo5 = ["This might be true!", true, false];

// choosing a random array name

fooID = "foo" + randomNumber(1, 5);

/* How would I make this work? -

alert(<value of fooID>[0]);
<value of fooID>[2] = true;

*/
```

What I'm trying to do is choose a random array (all are named foo__) and then do something with it.

Perhaps I could even target an array in a completely different way, not even requiring a fooID variable? I [looked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356221/how-to-set-a-variables-value-string-to-be-equal-to-a-key-in-an-array) in StackOverflow and found out that I should use dictionaries, but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use simply an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), because your data is iterable and you need a random number for getting the result out of it.

```js
function getRandomElement(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}

var foos = [
        ["This is true!", true, false],
        ["This is false!", false, false],
        ["This is probably false!", false, false],
        ["This is probably true!", true, false],
        ["This might be true!", true, false]
    ],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(getRandomElement(foos)[0]);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: While this is a neat solution for this specific case, it fails to realize that OP probably is unaware of brackets notation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: while bracket notation in combination with the window object might be a solution, it works only for systems with window object and works there only for global variables as well. so bracket notation with windows for own variables is not a good solution and it should be avoided wherever it is posssible, that means at any case.

Comment: The `window` context is ofc only applicable in a) the browser and b) in this trivial example. This does not reduce the approach's validity to dynamically access object properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), as the variables are defined globally, `window[/* array variable identifier */]`

```js
// here goes random number generator

// arrays with info

foo1 = ["This is true!", true, false];
foo2 = ["This is false!", false, false];
foo3 = ["This is probably false!", false, false];
foo4 = ["This is probably true!", true, false];
foo5 = ["This might be true!", true, false];

// choosing a random array name

fooID = window["foo" + 1  /* randomNumber(1, 5) */ ];

console.log(fooID);
```

Answer (score 2):

> > Perhaps I could even target an array in a completely different way,

```js
var foo = [
  ["This is true!", true, false],
  ["This is false!", false, false],
  ["This is probably false!", false, false],
  ["This is probably true!", true, false],
  ["This might be true!", true, false]
];

var fooItem = foo[Math.trunc(Math.random()*5)];
console.log(fooItem);
```

Indeed, just make an array inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want can be achieved using [brackets property notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), since you can make use of variables or any other valid JS expression elements inside the property name.

In your example, foo1 to foo6 exist as variables in the global namespace, which means they are all attached to the `window` object in a browser.

So store the name of the variable that you want to access in a variable you could for example name `accessor` and then access the corresponding variable like this:

```
window[accessor]
```

```js
// here goes random number generator

// arrays with info

foo1 = ["This is true!", true, false];
foo2 = ["This is false!", false, false];
foo3 = ["This is probably false!", false, false];
foo4 = ["This is probably true!", true, false];
foo5 = ["This might be true!", true, false];

// choosing a random array name

fooID = window["foo" + 3 /*randomNumber(1, 5)*/];

/* How would I make this work? -

alert(<value of fooID>[0]);
<value of fooID>[2] = true;

*/
```